# How to create response json from pandas csv in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

get error when use this

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols=[1,5,7])

return Response(df.to_json(),status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: MemoryError at /snippets/
No exception message supplied

Answer (score 0):

df.to_json (r'Path where the new JSON file will be stored\New File Name.json')

to need to first save the than send it to a response